# CAS authentication for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, cas

I have installed "WP Cassify" plugin to enable CAS login for my Wordpress.But after entering the username and password in CAS login screen, I am getting following error in my web browser:

**Error [ wp_cassify_do_ssl_web_request ] : SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate**

I don't know the reason behind this issue. I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I'm plugin author. This error become from 1.5.8 version because I would use wp_remote_get function instead of php cURL functions. So update to latest version 1.5.9. It solve the problem.

Best regards.